# Can I write/append logs to an compressed file which is located in hdfs?

Tags: logging, hadoop, compression, hdfs

I'm testing hadoop and hive, and I want to use them in log analysis.

Here I have a question, can I write/append log to  an compressed file which is located in hdfs?

Our system generate lots of log files every day, I can compress these logs every hour and them put them into hdfs.

But what if I want to write logs into files that was already in the hdfs and was compressed?

Is these files were not compressed, then this job seems easy, but how to write or append logs into an compressed log?

Can I do that?

Can anyone give me some advices or give me some examples?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is like any file system (but distributed). If the compression algorithm supports appending then is should be possible to do appending in HDFS. Note that only some of the Hadoop releases support HDFS append.

Comment: thank you Parveen, so it seems it is not possible to write or append log into an compressed files in hdfs. I will find some other way to do this job,  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the zlib distribution, there are two example programs that do this.  gzappend and gzlog.  You can get the zlib distribution from http://zlib.net .